# How to save array of LatLng with title and date in Firebase database android?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add the array of LatLng in my firebase database. I have added my title and data in my database but can't get the knowledge of storing array in my database.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534079/how-to-save-location-info-in-firebase) link but my problem is to stora array.

//To write in database.

```
@Override
public void writeNewPost(ArrayList<LatLng> latLng, DatabaseReference mDatabase,
            Events model, User user) {
    final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String key = mDatabase.child("events").push().getKey();

    Events events = new Events(userId, user.username, model.getEventTitle(), 
        model.getEventDateTime() latLng);

    Map<String, Object> eventsValues = events.toMapEvents();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/events/" + key, eventsValues);
    this.key = key;
    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);

}
```

//Model

```
public Map<String, Object> toMapEvents() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("userId", userId);
    result.put("username", username);
    result.put("eventTitle", eventTitle);
    result.put("eventDateTime", eventDateTime);
      //What to do
    return result;
}
```

How can i store my array in firebase?
Thanks .

Answer (score -1):

```
lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();   
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("nodename");            
ref.setValue(lineOptions);
```